# Wrong BIOS installed HP ENVY Notebook. No way to flash BIOS now

Tags: bios, hp-envy

I have my `HP 15-j Notebook` series 2013 model. I was not using the laptop for a long time. Now when i turned it on, its `BIOS` was causing trouble. 2 Blinking lights in `CAPSLOCK` in interval.

However i flashed the BIOS using WINDOWS + B option using external USB drive. The problem was i installed a `BIOS` of 2018 for another model. Now my original `BIOS` is not getting detected in USB drive. All time blinking 2 `CAPSLOCK` in interval.

Is there any other way to revert my BIOS update ? I have tried hard reset, etc etc. My last hope is here.

Note: If i load Same `BIOS` in the USB drive again it's patching the `BIOS` again. I can assume, my original `BIOS` is old, so HP is not downgrading it.

Comment: See this>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02693833

Comment: @Moab  it have explained above. The recovery method is not working. Windows + B using external USB is not working. It's blinking 2 capslock and not loading the bios from USB

Comment: Did you reset the cmos first?

Comment: I did hard reset CMOS and even kept CMOS battery out for few minutes after that.  You mean to dry the power right ? Holding 15 seconds without power ?

Comment: Yep, not sure what is wrong, the thumb drive needs to have the label HP_TOOLS before the bios recovery will recognize it.

Comment: Yes it is recognizing if the wrong bios is loaded. Because it's 2018. Orginal bios is 2013 both has been labelled as hp_tools